# Creating Unknown Number of Beans With Configuration From Properties-Files

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

My situation is that I have a properties-file to configure an unknown number of beans:

```
rssfeed.source[0]=http://feed.com/rss-news.xml
rssfeed.title[0]=Sample feed #1
rssfeed.source[1]=http://feed.com/rss-news2.xml
rssfeed.title[1]=Sample feed #2
:
```

I have a configuration class to read those properties:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rssfeed", locations = "classpath:/config/rssfeed.properties")
public class RssConfig {

  private List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
  private List<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();

  public List<String> getSource() {
    return source;
  }
  public List<String> getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {

  }
}
```

This is working nicely. However, now I want to create beans based on that. What I've tried so far is

1. add `@Bean`-methods and call them from `postConstruct()`

   ```
     @Bean
     @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
     public SourcePollingChannelAdapter createFeedChannelAdapter(int id, String url) {
       SourcePollingChannelAdapter channelAdapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
       channelAdapter.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       channelAdapter.setBeanName("feedChannelAdapter" + id);
       channelAdapter.setSource(createMessageSource(id, url));
       return channelAdapter;
     }

     @Bean
     @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
     public FeedEntryMessageSource createMessageSource(int id, String url) {
       try {
         FeedEntryMessageSource messageSource = new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL(url), "");
         messageSource.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
         messageSource.setBeanName("feedChannelAdapter" + id + ".source");
         return messageSource;
       } catch (Throwable e) {
         Utility.throwAsUncheckedException(e);
         return null;
       }
     }

     @Bean
     @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
     public QueueChannel createFeedChannel(int id, String url) {
       QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();
       channel.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       channel.setBeanName("feedChannel" + id);
       return channel;
     }

     @PostConstruct
     public void postConstruct() {
       for (int x = 0; x < source.size(); x++) {
         createFeedChannelAdapter(x, source.get(x));
       }
     }
   ```

   However, Spring tries to autowire the parameters to those methods rather than using the parameters I provided in `postConstruct()`.
2. a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. However, here I don't have access to the properties-file or the `RssConfig`-bean from above as it's called too early in the lifecycle.

What do I need to do generate those dynamic number of beans? I'm probably just a tiny little step away... I prefer a Java configuration-solution over an XML-solution.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160221/how-do-i-create-beans-programmatically-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the bean definitions (not call `@Bean` methods), so `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` or `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` are the best ways to do that currently. You can grab the properties file and bind to it using `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` (in Spring Boot) instead of using `@ConfigurationProperties`, or maybe you could use a parent context or a standalone `SpringApplication` to create and bind your `RssConfig` inside your bean definition registration code.

Comment: Whow, the chief answered my question :) Yes, I got it to work with `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. The tough part was to scan through the source of the namespace handlers to set up the stuff manually. In case anyone reads this I recommend to create a typical XML-setup and then look at the bean registry to get an idea what all the important beans look like.

Comment: Hi Dave, is there a better way to do this in 2020?

Comment: You would still have to extract the properties and create the beans. There is the functional bean registration API now (in `GenericApplicationContext`), so I guess that is a new option.