# Spring dynamic bean definition autowire

Tags: java, spring

So first short introduction:
I have a working application context, now I want to create a new bean factory that extends it with some dynamic bean definitions.
So i create a new instance of `DefaultListableBeanFactory` passing base application context as parent.
Then I create a new bean definition:

```
BeanDefinition beanDef = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(beanType)
                                              .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
                                              .setLazyInit(false)
                                              .setAbstract(false)
                                              .setDependencyCheck(AbstractBeanDefinition.DEPENDENCY_CHECK_ALL)
                                              .getBeanDefinition();
```

and at the end I register it with newly created bean factory

```
beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDef);
```

then some time later i would like to get new instance of that bean so I do:

```
Object beanInstance = beanFactory.getBean(jobType);
```

now i would expect that fields annotated with `@Autowired` are initialized.. but no. Calling `beanFactory.autowireBean(beanInstance)` does not help.

After looking up some other bean definitions in base application context i can see that my definitoin does not have any attributes and that I can add them by calling `beanDef.setAttribute()` but that requires me to know them in advance.

Now question. Is there a way to create fully initialized bean definition programmatically so it is autowired correctly?

Comment: check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/28550486/1876620](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28550486/1876620)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring - Programmatically generate a set of beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374000/spring-programmatically-generate-a-set-of-beans)

Answer (score 1):

So so i found out what i was missing:
`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`
it needs to be added to bean factory to fire up the `@Autowired` and `@Value` annotations.

also for `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` you need `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`

Bean factory created for application context by spring boot has total of 12 bean post processors so it is possible that some other are needed to get all features.