# How to register collection of FactoryBeans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a custom implementation of `org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean` spring interface. If I create its instance and register it as a bean, then it's getting registered by spring and I can use values produced by it, as expected:

```
@Bean
public FactoryBean<T> create() {
     return new CustomFactoryBean();
}
```

However, I have a property, that is a list of strings and for each string I want to create a separate FactoryBean instance, then I want to autowire a collection of values where each value is generated by a separate `FactoryBean`. Is there a way to do that?

Ideally I want to do something like that:

```
@Bean
public Collection<FactoryBean<T>> createMultiple(@Value("${someproperty}") Set<String> values) {
     return values.stream().map(s -> new CustomFactoryBean(s)).collect(toList());
}

@Bean
public SomeService createService(Collection<T> createdValues) { //every value is produced by a separate factory
     return new SomeService(createdValues);
}
```

The code above unfortunately doesn't work, it just registeres a bean that is a collection of instances of a `FactoryBean`, but doesn't register factories...

Comment: check this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374000/spring-programmatically-generate-a-set-of-beans

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a BeanDefinitionBuilder and programmatically registered all the factory beans into application context inside createMultiple method.

```
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry passed as parameterand use
registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

Reference :
[Spring - Programmatically generate a set of beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374000/spring-programmatically-generate-a-set-of-beans)