# How to instantiate separate bean member each time class is instantiate

Tags: java, spring

```
  private Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfBytes = new Last60MinutesArray();
  @Bean
  Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfBytes()
  {
    return last60MinutesOfBytes;
  }

  private Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfStartedTrackersCount = new Last60MinutesArray();
  @Bean
  Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfStartedTrackersCount()
  {
    return last60MinutesOfStartedTrackersCount;
  }

  @Bean
  InLast60MinutesChart bytesUploadedInLastMinutesChart()
  {
    return new InLast60MinutesChart("Bytes Uploaded"
        ,last60MinutesOfBytes);
  }

  @Bean
  InLast60MinutesChart uploadsStartedInLastMinutesChart()
  {
    return new InLast60MinutesChart("Uploads Started"
        ,last60MinutesOfStartedTrackersCount);
  }
```

I'm creating two beans of type `InLast60MinutesChart` which takes a `Last60MinutesArray` in the constructor.  I rather not have 'Last60MinutesArray' brought in through the constructor but rather instantiated in the `InLast60MinutesChart`. However, I still want two separate instances of 'Last60MinutesArray' and I want them both to be Beans so I can use springs annotations such as @Scheduled.
Thanks for any thoughts :)

I want it to look something like this:

```
  @Bean
  InLast60MinutesChart bytesUploadedInLastMinutesChart()
  {
    return new InLast60MinutesChart("Bytes Uploaded");
  }

  @Bean
  InLast60MinutesChart uploadsStartedInLastMinutesChart()
  {
    return new InLast60MinutesChart("Uploads Started");
  }
```

```
public class InLast60MinutesChart
{
  @Autowired
  protected Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesArray;
}
```

And I want each `InLast60MinutesChart` to have its own distinct `Last60MinutesArray` and lets also say I want 50 instances of  `InLast60MinutesChart` and so I don't really want to create a Bean for each `Last60MinutesArray`.  I have to create a Bean for each `InLast60MinutesChart` but I'd rather not create that many `Last60MinutesArray` Beans on top of that along with any other Beans I want to add to the `InLast60MinutesChart` Bean.  Kind of weird scenario but I hope if gets my question across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your title doesn't actually match your question description, but in case you want something like it says in your title, then you need beans with a scope of "prototype".
by default, Spring beans are Singletons. they are created once and injected each time they are autowired. However, if you'd like a new instance of the bean each time it is autowired, then you need to specify a "scope" of type "prototype"

```
@Bean("bytesChart")
@Scope("prototype")
public InLast60MinutesChart bytesUploadedInLastMinutesChart(@Qualifier("bytesCount") Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfBytes) {
    return new InLast60MinutesChart("Bytes Uploaded", last60MinutesOfBytes);
}
```

now, a new instance of "InLast60MinutesChart" will be created each time it is autowired.
there are other scopes as well, most of them are not useful :P

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Comment: I thought this might do it from the look of it but when I tested it out I realized that this creates fake/prototype objects.  I'm looking for something similar to this but creating real instances of `Last60MinutesArray`

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "fake/prototype" objects...this is Java, not JavaScript.
The annotation instructs the container to create a new instance of the bean each time is it autowired. to test this, you can put a breakpoint in the function that creates the bean and see for your self.

Comment: Okay you're right, my first test using the debugger was showing me weird results.  I created a new project and ran some experiments and yes @Scope("prototype") is what I was looking for thanks :)

Comment: According to the question description, prototype scope is not what you want. Prototype creates a new bean *every time it is requested* (via e.g. `applicationContext.getBean(Last60MinutesArray.class)`. If the beans you are requesting also perform scheduled tasks, this will probably not behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple `@Bean` definitions of the same type available in the application context, you can define your `Last60MinutesArray` instances as `@Bean`s and then provide them a specific bean name as a qualifier, as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean("bytesCount")
    public Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfBytes() {
         return new Last60MinutesArray();
    }

    @Bean("trackersCount")
    public Last60MinutesArray trackersCount () {
        return new Last60MinutesArray();
    }
}
```

This makes your `Last60MinutesArray`s into full-fledged Spring beans which are part of the application lifecycle (and among other things, capable of having `@Scheduled` methods as you desire).

Afterwards, you can pass the relevant `@Bean` to the proper `InLast60MinutesChart` by using `@Qualifier`, as follows:

```java
  // in the same class or another marked as @Configuration

    @Bean("bytesChart")
    public InLast60MinutesChart bytesUploadedInLastMinutesChart(@Qualifier("bytesCount") Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfBytes) {
        return new InLast60MinutesChart("Bytes Uploaded", last60MinutesOfBytes);
    }

    @Bean("uploadsChart")
    public InLast60MinutesChart uploadsStartedInLastMinutesChart(@Qualifier("trackersCount") Last60MinutesArray last60MinutesOfStartedTrackersCount ) {
        return new InLast60MinutesChart("Uploads Started", last60MinutesOfStartedTrackersCount);
    }
```

Note that your `InLast60MinutesChart` beans should *likely* also be qualified, as using `@Autowired` to inject either of them (or either of the `Last60MinutesArray`s) will yield a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` upon injection since there is more than one bean of the matching type. In this case, autowiring would also require a `@Qualifier`, e.g. as follows:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("uploadsChart")
    private InLast60MinutesChart uploadsChart;

}
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about the specific instances, you can inject all beans of the given type as follows:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

   @Autowired
   private List<InLast60MinutesChart> charts;

}
```

which you can then iterate over.

Note that you do not have to qualify the bean names if you instead mark one of them as `@Primary`, but judging from your code, this is probably not what you want to do.

It would also likely help you to go through the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers), which goes into a bit more detail.

---

> Lets say I create 50 Beans of InLast60MinutesChart in the config. Is there a way that I don't then have to create 50 Beans of Last60MinutesArray / any other bean that I may want included in InLast60MinutesChart. Also keeping in mind that I want them to each be a separate instance.

The number of beans that you need to create is an important detail, making the maintenance effort non-trivial for the above naïve approach. In such a case, you will most likely want to basically do what I said above, but programmatically:

1. Create `n` `Last60MinutesArray` beans programmatically, each of them having a separate name (what kind of pattern you want to use for the naming is up to you).
2. Create `n` `InLast60MinutesChart` beans programmatically, which have a constructor taking a `Last60MinutesArray`.

The important part is that you must keep track of which `Last60MinutesArray`s to pass to which `InLast60MinutesChart`, essentially emulating the above declarative bean creation.

Instead of repeating already-present information, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28550486) answer for programmatically registering beans in the application context using  `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry()`.

Comment: Lets say I create 50 Beans of `InLast60MinutesChart` in the config.  Is there a way that I don't then have to create 50 Beans of `Last60MinutesArray` / any other bean that I may want included in `InLast60MinutesChart`.  Also keeping in mind that I want them to each be a separate instance.