# Spring Boot create a list of managed prototype beans from database configuration

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I'm currently developing a Spring server application using Spring Boot.

I need to develop a system where some InputStream will be sent from either the local `File System`, or from `FTP`, or some other source to specific `InputStreamConsumer` instances, all this configured in database. The `InputStreamConsumer` already are managed beans.

My `InputStreamProviders` are likely to be `Prototype beans`. They will not be used by other beans, but they'll need to use a `TaskScheduler` and periodically send `InputStreams` to their InputStreamConsumers.

**Long story short, I need to instantiate a list of `Beans` from external configuration using Spring. Is there a way to do that?**

Comment: why do you need to make that a Spring bean exactly? This is a general Spring framework question btw.

Comment: The `InputStreamProvider` instances will be either file consumers, or rest controllers, or anything that can retrieve input streams and push them to managed instances of `InputStreamConsumer`. Therefore some of them will need to register a `Task` to a `TaskScheduler`. Some of them will need other beans. I want it to be automatically managed by Spring, so the `@Configuration InputStreamProviderFactory` won't have to now all their dependencies. This is why I want to make them Spring Beans.

Comment: Have you tyed to create that beans programmatic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160221/how-do-i-create-beans-programmatically-in-spring-boot

Comment: I am not sure I get your use case properly but it'd be probably better if your singleton beans were responsible to create instances of those `InputStreamProvider` instead of trying to make them a first-class citizen of the container. The `TaskScheduler` dependency can be a dependency of the thing that creates the provider instance.

Comment: @Stephane Nicoll : Not all `InputStreamProvider` subtypes will need a `TaskScheduler`. And maybe there will be `RestControllers` in those subtypes. I don't know yet what kind of `InputStreamProvider` I will have to create, and what dependencies they will need. This is why I wanted them to be managed beans. I may be thinking wrong. I will consider this solution if I don't find a solution to this exact problem :).

Comment: @Ralph : Thank you for your answer too, I just tried it, but my `@Autowire` annotations in my  `InputStreamProvider` instances don't seem to be taken in account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to the link @Ralph mentioned in his comment ([How do I create beans programmatically in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160221/how-do-i-create-beans-programmatically-in-spring-boot)), I managed to do what I wanted to.

I'm using a `@Configuration class InputStreamProviderInstantiator implements BeanFactoryAware`.

The post didn't mention how to process the `@Autowire` annotations in the `InputStreamProvider` instances, though, so I'm posting here how to do it :

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class InputStreamProviderInitializer implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory factory;
    @Inject
    InputStreamProviderConfigurationRepository configurationRepository;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory) {
        Assert.state(factory instanceof AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory, "wrong bean factory type");
        this.factory = (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory) factory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeInputStreamProviders() {
         for (InputStreamProviderConfigurationEntity configuration : configurationRepository.findAll()) {
             InputStreamProvider provider = // PROVIDER CREATION, BLAH, BLAH, BLAH
             String providerName = "inputStreamSource"+configuration.getId();
             factory.autowireBean(provider);
             factory.initializeBean(source, providerName);
             factory.registerSingleton(providerName, source); // I don't think it's mandatory since the providers won't be called by other beans.
         }
    }
}
```