# Create N number of beans with BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create *N* number of beans dynamically using `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. Based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922318/creating-unknown-number-of-beans-with-configuration-from-properties-files) question, I opted to use `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` for my use case.

I have the following defined in my `application.yml`:

```
app:
  downstream-services:
    rest:
      jsonPlaceHolder:
        url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos
        api-type: io.mateo.dynamicbeans.JsonPlaceHolderApi
```

Which gets wired up to a `ConfigiruationProperties` class here: https://github.com/ciscoo/dynamicbeans/blob/master/src/main/java/io/mateo/dynamicbeans/FeignConfigurationProperties.java

I then want to inject that `ConfigiruationProperties` class along with a factory bean that I defined here: https://github.com/ciscoo/dynamicbeans/blob/master/src/main/java/io/mateo/dynamicbeans/FeignClientAutoConfiguration.java

So now I have the following:

https://github.com/ciscoo/dynamicbeans/blob/master/src/main/java/io/mateo/dynamicbeans/FeignClientFactoryPostProcessor.java

```
@Component
public class FeignClientFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    private final FeignConfigurationProperties properties;
    private final FeignClientFactory feignClientFactory;

    public FeignClientFactoryPostProcessor(FeignConfigurationProperties properties, FeignClientFactory feignClientFactory) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.feignClientFactory = feignClientFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        properties.getDownstreamServices().getRest().forEach((beanName, props) -> makeClient(beanName, props, registry));
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // no-op
    }

    private void makeClient(String beanName, FeignClientProperties props, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(props.getApiType());
        beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(() -> feignClientFactory.create(props));
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
    }
}
```

The single bean it should create is to injected in a service class here: https://github.com/ciscoo/dynamicbeans/blob/master/src/main/java/io/mateo/dynamicbeans/JsonPlaceHolderService.java

The problem I'm running into is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.mateo.dynamicbeans.FeignClientFactoryPostProcessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.mateo.dynamicbeans.FeignClientFactoryPostProcessor.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1262) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.mateo.dynamicbeans.FeignClientFactoryPostProcessor.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

But when I remove the `final` keyword from the two properties and the defined constructor, I get a `NullPointerException`.

So how do I dynamically create *N* number of beans **so that they will be available in time** for any of my `@Service` classes to use?

---

I'm aware of https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign. I recreated my issue here to illustrate the same problem I'm having in a different project with dynamically creating SOAP clients.

**Update**: Doing the following changes: https://github.com/ciscoo/dynamicbeans/commit/4f16de9d03271025cd65d95932a3e854c0619c29, now I am able to accomplish my use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the answer to the question that you have linked to suggests, you can’t inject dependencies into a bean factory post-processor. Rather than injecting your configuration properties class, you’ll need to bind it programmatically. In Spring Boot 2.x, that is [achieved using the `Binder` API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#configuration-property-binding):

> The new Binder API can also be used outside of `@ConfigurationProperties` directly in your own code. For example, the following will bind to a `List` of `PersonName` objects:
>
> ```
> List<PersonName> people = Binder.get(environment)
>     .bind("my.property", Bindable.listOf(PersonName.class))   
>     .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
> ```
>
> The configuration source could be represented in YAML like this:
>
> ```
> my:
>   property:
>   - first-name: Jane
>     last-name: Doe
>   - first-name: John
>     last-name: Doe
> ```

Comment: That worked out perfectly, thank you! One side question, is it recommended that the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` be marked as `@Component` or defined as a `@Bean` within in `@Configuration` class?

Comment: I would define it as a `static` `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class. Declaring the method as `static` means that the bean method can be called without instantiating its class. This will prevent the creation of your post-processor (which needs to happen very early) from causing anything also to be created earlier than wanted.

Comment: What is the recommended way to get hold of `Environment` in the post processor?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi As shown in [the code](https://github.com/ciscoo/dynamicbeans/commit/4f16de9d03271025cd65d95932a3e854c0619c29) that's linked at the end of the question, you can implement `EnvironmentAware`. I can't recall if you can use constructor injection for the `Environment`. You may want to try that as an alternative as, if it works, it would allow your post-processor to be immutable.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks! Constructor injection works as well.